# Blocks missing from homepage after logout

Tags: views, blocks, users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Content not showing when logged out!](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/30831/content-not-showing-when-logged-out)

I don't understand why this is happening. When logged in everything is fine but when logged out some blocks like slideshow and some views go missing. What's annoying is that I have two jCarousel slideshows on my page and only one of them disappears after logout.

I've checked the user permissions and I don't find any anomalies there. Can anyone please suggest why this could be happening?

Comment: Did you check the permissions on the blocks themselves?

Comment: Yes I've checked the user roles for each of those missing blocks and everything seems to be fine. I even put a check on all three user roles in blocks configuration but it remains the same. This was fine before and happened all of a sudden.

Comment: You can try checking the permissions for the Views as well.  Unfortunately, you also have to check permissions for all of the content displayed in the views.  Do you have a backup of when things were working well?  If you can compare a working version with a non-working version, you might be able to find the solution quicker...

Comment: I've checked permissions on views as well and still no luck. I don't have a backup of working things so that's out of question. How do I check permissions on all the contents? By the way I remember this happened when I was working on the taxonomy problem in views and it was fine before that. Can there be some connection with this?

Comment: I am closing this, as the [new question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/30831) includes this question.