# Content not showing when logged out!

Tags: users, nodes

I don't know why this is happening, but none of my content are displayed when logged out. All the content in views, blocks, everything disappear upon logout. As far as I can remember, I haven't touched any permission. In fact I created this project only a few days ago.

I have two jCarousel slideshows and a few views connected with nodequeues on my site among other things; all of them disappear upon logging out. I have already checked all permissions on views, blocks, and everything I could find.

What can I do to resolve the issue?

As an experiment I searched for a content through the search bar, and the page returned said access denied.

EDIT: Problem solved. The solution has been posted in [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/31603/views-disappear-upon-logout) thread.

Comment: WHy dont you try rebuilding permisssions ?

Comment: Just did that and cleared the cache. Still the problem persists. I don't know what else I can try.. :(

Answer (score 1):

Go in admin/user/permissions and check if the "access content" [and "search content"] is checked for the    anonymous user

Comment: The url takes me to the dashboard and there is no "access content" there. Is it for Drupal 7?

Comment: Are you in drupal 6 or 7?

Comment: I'm on Drupal 7.

Comment: Ok ^^
Check if "View published content" is checked

Comment: "View published content" is checked for all three users.

Answer (score 1):

site.com/admin/content/node-settings/rebuild
Sometimes Drupal node permissions get corrupted. When this happens, rebuilding the node permissions can solve the problem. Please be advised that if you have a lot of nodes, this can take a very long time.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should check permission under **Node** for the different content types here http://www.example.com/admin/people/permissions if everything is fine then you have check your code may be you are overriding [hook_node_access](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_access/7) in your custom module.

Comment: I have neither built a custom module nor I've added any sort of code to project. But this is happening nonetheless.

Comment: Is front page working for anonymous users?

Comment: No, all contents on front page disappears.

Comment: Are you using panels?

Comment: Yes I'm using panels but not on the front page. Could it have anything to do with this? Because my previous problem started before I used panels. And my current problem has just started today.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a problem with cache. Check it turning cache off for page and blocks.