# Views disappear upon logout

Tags: views, nodes

I haven't touched any default permissions for views in my site but they disappear for anonymous and authenticated users. In permissions 'view published content' is enabled for the mentioned roles. I have even tried rebuilding the permissions but no use.

I also checked permissions in views i.e, `Access` option in Block Settings and tried all combinations of it's options but still no use.

All other contents (shown through `print render($page['content'])`) are fine and displays upon logout but it's only the views that disppear.

I'm using Drupal 7.

I don't know what seems to be the problem, and what else to try.

Comment: There is no checkbox called `access all views` in permissions. Are you talking about `/people/permissions`?

Comment: I think you meant `Bypass views access control` in Drupal 7 right? Did that too but still the problem persists. :(

Comment: I was talking about D6. Sorry i will recheck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by enabling the `Disable SQL Rewriting` option in `Query Settings` in my views. This action might have some security implications so lets hope for the best for now.

You can find the discussion [here](http://drupal.org/node/1276450).

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with Flexslider.

After checking al lthe permissions issues, I remembered that the content for my slides was "unpublished". I switched it to "Published" and, VOILA! It worked.

It's a common practice to have the slides "unpublished", so I don't know why this makes a difference, but it did.